# How to add a X86 backend pass in LLVM without having to rebuild all sorts of shared libraries, including clang?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

> How to add a X86 backend pass in LLVM without having to rebuild all sorts of shared libraries, including clang?

After having studied the LLVM "middle-end" for a while (`IR`/`opt`), I've decided to move into the backend.

Here, I've created a very simply `MachineFunctionPass` in `.../lib/Target/X86/`, which compiles just fine.

Now, from what I understand, I cannot just load the LLVM backend pass using `llc`, like it was possible for `opt` w.r.t. IR-passes. Instead, I've have to build the new pass into the LLVM infrastructure, so I issue the command `cmake . --build` from my `llvm/build` directory.

This has the effect that all sorts of shared libraries are build again, including all kinds of `clang` specific .so files.

The problem is that this take more than 30 minutes, so this cannot be the correct way of building a simple backend pass. How do I quickly configure and build the pass into LLVM, so that I can use it with `llc`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in LLVM, but this seems to work for me:

1. Go the LLVM build directory: `cd ~/llvm/build/`.
2. Proceed to the `llc` build directory: `cd tools/llc/`.
3. Build `llc`: `cmake --build`.

Now, instead of using the topmost `cmake` build script, which causes the entire project to be build (changed files and dependencies), only the `llc` tool is build.

I haven't tested this thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different from the above post:

```
cmake -G Ninja ...
```

to configure llvm.

Then

```
ninja llc
```

should work fine.

Comment: Why does default target build (almost) every single executable? Shouldn't the build system detect that only dependencies for "llc" have changed?

Comment: Probably because of dependencies. You didn't say what file you changed and what build system you were using.